# Некорректное отображение ScrollView

Tags: swift, scrollview, swiftui

При запуске приложения на девайсе ScrollView не скроллится до крайних элементов, отображает элементы из середины. При переходе на детальный экран и возврате обратно работает как должен (скроллится с первого и до последнего элемента). На превью так же работает как должен.

```swift
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    VStack {
        ForEach(recentImages.recentImages) { image in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(image: image)) {
                ImageView(imageUrl:image.urls.small)
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 1000)
}
```

[Проект на github](https://github.com/glori0s/PictureViewer)

Comment: на каком именно девайсе? на симуляторе той же модели нормально показывается?,

Comment: На XS Max с iOS 13.0 отображалось некорректно, в то время как на симуляторе работало нормально. Проблемы крылась в версии iOS, установленной на iPhone. Лечится накатыванием последней версии iOS.